# Is homotopy a one-way mapping?

Tags: algebraic-topology

If there exists a homotopy $f \simeq g$, does this imply that a reverse homotopy $g \simeq f$ exists too, or this is not true in general?

Example: a homotopy from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to origin point $(0, 0)$.

A direct homotopy from identity map $\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ to $p_0: x \mapsto 0$, which sends every point $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $0$, exists: $H_{\rightarrow}(t) = t\cdot p_0 + (1-t)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$.

Is it ok to claim that $H_{\leftarrow}(t) = (1-t)\cdot p_0 + t\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$ is a reverse homotopy?

Comment: It is correct.  Homotopy between maps is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Thanks @DouglasMolin, it is indeed is, so reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity are all included, cool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A homotopy
from $f$ to $g$ is a
continuous map $H:X\times[0,1]\to Y$ with $H(x,0)=f(x)$
and $H(x,1)=g(x)$. Then one defines a "reverse homotopy" $\tilde H$
with
$$\tilde H(x,t)=H(x,1-t)$$
from $g$ to $f$.